# What makes light to be a special part of the electromagnetic spectrum that it has a particle?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, photons

Why only light has photons while x-ray or micro/radio waves don't?

If we build a device that can iterate over all frequencies, what will be so special about the light range that it will start to generate photons while in all other ranges no photons will be made?

Are there special 0 mass particles for x-rays and radio waves or do they also generate photons? (the latter is highly unlikely since radio doesn't travel in a straight line)

Comment: Why do you think that only visible light is made of photons?

Comment: What makes you think that?

Comment: I didn't say it's made of photons, it's a wave and a particle but other parts of the spectrum aren't, why? @AndreiGeanta

Comment: All EM radiation has photons. There is nothing unique about light in this respect.

Comment: @shinzou,  But they are.

Comment: Is there a difference between radio photons and x-ray photons then? And how do the photons of radio travel in a non straight line manner? like out of horizon radio or around buildings and walls? Do these photons exhibit special properties that makes them "bouncier"? @JohnRennie

Comment: @shinzou, Yes, there is - it is the energy (frequency, wavelength).

Comment: @shinzou all EM waves travel in straight lines except when they are diffracted. Diffraction increases with wavelength so radio waves diffract more then X-rays. For more on this see [Why does wavelength affect diffraction?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/125903/why-does-wavelength-affect-diffraction)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Light and all electromagnetic frequencies emerge from a superposition of photons, the underlying quantum mechanical state of [electrodynamics, QED.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics)

> Are there special 0 mass particles for x-rays and radio waves

They are photons of mass zero and energy = to $h*ν$, where $ν$ is the frequency of the wave and $h$ is the [Planck constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_constant)

> or do they also generate photons? (the latter is highly unlikely since radio doesn't travel in a straight line)

They are composed out of zillions of photons, all frequencies of electromagnetic radiation.

It is the classical electromagnetic wave that is deflected easily by obstacles. This means radio frequency photons will have time dependent build ups of superposition to the classical radio wave, but the mathematics is there and it is photons all the [way to zero frequency.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Light_spectrum.svg)